# How to respond to co-worker who suggest you may be gay?

Tags: work-environment, lgbt+, coworkers

In group conversations, certain co-workers would make offensive remarks to suggest I may be gay. I am a male gay and am not out of the closet.

Examples of such remarks:

- "Would you prefer an introduction to a male lover instead?",
- "I'm sure you will be comfortable at the new location. There are plenty of men there.".

What is the best way I can react/respond to such comments without compromising my desire to remain closeted?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [interpersonal.se]! What is your desired output here? What do you want to accomplish? Add these details in your question.  Try also to add your culture as it may help answering your question better. As it currently stands, it's too broad.

Comment: It would also be nice if you could explain your environment a bit more. Is it generally accpeted to be gay in your country/state? Are there other gays you know of in the company? What happened to them? Is this guy serious or does he just make these 'typical gay jokes'? What makes this person think you are gay?

Comment: @AJ Questionable goal. But *"not out of the closet"* makes it fair for us to assume OP is wanting to stop these remarks and limit any further public conjecture of his sexuality... Not that I have the faintest idea how to answer that

Comment: The goal seems a bit unclear, do you want to prevent the person from "accidentally" outing you? Or to convince them that you aren't gay if the country/culture is sub-optimal for being out?

Comment: I rephrased your question to be a little more direct with a goal/intent based off the vibe I get from your post. If this is off base, please rollback/edit appropriately.

Comment: This question might also be a good fit for [Workplace.se]